# How to save the following python output result to .csv format

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

How can I save the result from this code to .csv format?

```
import re
import CSV

text = open('example.txt').read()
pattern = r'([0-9]+)[:]([0-9]+)[:](.*)'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
for match in regex.finditer(text):
      result = ("{},{}".format(match.group(2),match.group(3)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can generate the CSV as follows:

```
import re

text = open('example.txt').read()
pattern = r'([0-9]+)[:]([0-9]+)[:](.*)'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
with open('csv_file.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    # Add header row with two columns
    csv_file.write('{},{}\n'.format('Id', 'Tile'))
    for match in regex.finditer(text):
          result = ("{},{}".format(match.group(2),match.group(3)))
          csv_file.write('{}\n'.format(result))
```

Comment: thanks ...this is what I want.

Comment: but if i want to put the two groups under Id and tile columns how to

Comment: I updated the answer to include a header row with the columns.

Comment: Thank you very much........, sir

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, should be with open('csv_file.csv', 'w') as csv_file instead of with open('csv_file.csv', 'a') as csv_file, this will replace the file each time instead of appending.

Comment: I was about to ask this .. thanks, you solved the problem